# Error Setting Data Source

Tags: java, android, media-player, datasource

So I keep getting this error :

```
07-27 17:13:13.817: INFO/My Music Test(11215): Initializing: Song Path - /mnt/sdcard/music/Changing.mp3
07-27 17:13:13.817: ERROR/My Music Test(11215): Error setting data source!
07-27 17:13:13.817: WARN/System.err(11215): java.lang.IllegalStateException
07-27 17:13:13.817: WARN/System.err(11215):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(Native Method)
07-27 17:13:13.817: WARN/System.err(11215):     at com.laytproducts.mymusictest.Game.initGame(Game.java:229)
07-27 17:13:13.817: WARN/System.err(11215):     at com.laytproducts.mymusictest.Game$2.onClick(Game.java:258)
07-27 17:13:13.817: WARN/System.err(11215):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
07-27 17:13:13.817: WARN/System.err(11215):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8818)
07-27 17:13:13.817: WARN/System.err(11215):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-27 17:13:13.817: WARN/System.err(11215):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-27 17:13:13.817: WARN/System.err(11215):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
07-27 17:13:13.817: WARN/System.err(11215):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4701)
07-27 17:13:13.817: WARN/System.err(11215):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-27 17:13:13.827: WARN/System.err(11215):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-27 17:13:13.827: WARN/System.err(11215):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-27 17:13:13.827: WARN/System.err(11215):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-27 17:13:13.827: WARN/System.err(11215):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Since there is nothing wrong with the path there has to be something wrong with how I am setting up the MediaPlayer. It works the first time, but when I try and play a different song I get this error.

Code for ending MediaPlayer:

```
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
```

Code for starting:

```
        mp.setDataSource(currentSongPath);//Error is here
        mp.setVolume(100f, 100f);

        mp.prepare();
        Random mpRandom = new Random(27);
        int maxDur = mp.getDuration() - 30000;
        mpStartPos = mpRandom.nextInt(maxDur);
        mp.seekTo(mpStartPos);
        Log.i("My Music Test","Initializing: Start Pos - " + mpStartPos);
        mp.start();
```

I have been coding for about 6 hours straight now so most likely I am missing something really stupid.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After calling release() the object is not available again. Are you calling a new MediaPlayer before setting data source?

Comment: Yea i changed it to reset() and it fixed it. I couldn't post my own answer because less than 100 rep? anyway Ill give you best answer since you posted XD I am just tired, made stupid mistake